# Error starting android studio - getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android

I had been using `OpenJDK` for android studio. Recently I migrated to Oracle JDK 8.

Now, when I try to start android studio using **./studio.sh**, I get following error.

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.awt.Toolkit
        at java.awt.Component.<clinit>(Component.java:593)
        at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:237)
        at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:224)
        at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:87)`

I have set JAVA_HOME and have verified by putting echo statement in studio.sh file.

Can anybody help to identify problem? Or do I need to go back to OpenJDK or reinstall Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Use this to see different Java versions that you installed :

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Now you should see a list containing all java versions on your system . Select the one with path : `/opt/jdk/jdk1.7.0_71/bin/java` and hopefully that will do the trick.